# Sticky CSS Sidebar without fixed width [No JS]

Tags: html, css

I have a question, I want to have my window split vertically

```
-----------
|Div 1 |D2|
|      |  |
-----------

#D2{
   position: fixed;
   top: 0;
   right: 0;
   height: 100vh
}
```

Here's the catch: D2 has an image, that scales proportionally, so the width is depended on the height.
Currently Div 1 is taking the full width (100%) and I don't know how to get it to do: 100vw-(#D2[val])vw

Comment: Do you have to use `fixed` positioning?

Comment: See code above, it states:
#D2{position: FIXED;...}

Comment: what about sticky instead fixed, so it is part of the layout and will be fixed at screen position set http://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/VaaaRK (add lots of content to make grow. You can copy/paste from here fake content : http://html-ipsum.com or  at any other lorem ipsum sites )

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qZZNGP - it does not wrap before D2

Answer (score 0):

Flex ?  play with this snippet at http://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/VaaaRK or run it below here.

If you think `flex` still too much up to date, then you can use `display:table;` http://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/WwwGXr

```css
/* 101 */

body {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
}
#one {
  flex: 1;
}
img {
  display: block;
  height: 100vh
}
/* extra */

body {
  background: #F4BB2D
}
#one {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align:right;
  color: #89870A;
  font-size: 7vw;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px black, -1px -1px 1px gray
}
img {
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="one">
  Click Full Page <br/> Or Close
</div>
<div id="two">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/500/nature/6" />
</div>
```

added some extra terrestrial words to try break it pushing D2 under

```css
/* 101 */

body {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
}
#one {
  flex: 1;
}
img {
  display: block;
  height: 100vh
}
/* extra */

body {
  background: #F4BB2D
}
#one {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align:right;
  color: #89870A;
  font-size: 7vw;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px black, -1px -1px 1px gray
}
img {
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="one">
  <blocquote>ClickFullPageOrCloseClickFullPageOrCloseClickFullPageOrCloseClickFullPageOrCloseClickFullPageOrCloseClickFullPageOrCloseClickFullPageOrCloseClickFullPageOrCloseClickFullPageOrCloseClickFullPageOrCloseClickFullPageOrCloseClickFullPageOrCloseClickFullPageOrCloseClickFullPageOrCloseClickFullPageOrCloseClickFullPageOrCloseClickFullPageOrClose<br/>
    <cite> Zi stutterer that came from mars </cite></blockquote>
</div>
<div id="two">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/500/nature/6" />
</div>
```

Comment: Actually it does wrap @MarcWent, it is merely so that your 'Faaalex' contains 132 characters which _cannot_ be wrapped as it is considered a single word. There isn't a layout option that will not trip over this. Try adding a couple of spaces between some of the a's and you'll see it will wrap nicely

Comment: @MarcWent in case of an extraterrestrial word, you may allow html to grow bigger than the screen width : http://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/bppwWN   and you can use break-word http://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/pyyEwE